# counting the number of times a character appears in a file in a case insensitive manner using C language

Tags: c, file-handling, case-insensitive

The problem statement : a C program to count the number of times a character appears in the File. character is considered Case insensitive.
I have converted both the input character and character from the file to upper case so that none of the occurrence of the character goes uncounted. but when am executing this on an online editor am getting the result as "wrong answer" the editor isn`t accepting this code. what is the mistake in this code??

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main
    {
     FILE *fp;
     char filename[20];
     char character;
     char compare;
     int to_upper1;
     int to_upper2;
     int count=0;
     printf("\nEnter the file name");
     scanf("%s", filename);
     fp = fopen(filename,"r");
     if(fp == NULL)
     {
       exit(-1);
     }
     printf("\nEnter the character to be counted");
     scanf("%c", &character);
     to_upper1 = toupper(character);
     while((compare = fgets(fp)) != EOF)
     {
       to_upper2 = toupper(compare);
       if(to_upper1 == to_upper2)
          count++;
     }
     printf("\nFile \'%s\' has %d instances of letter \'%c\'", filename, count,      character);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you compiled this at all? Tested it?

Comment: `sed s/fgets/fgetc/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few errors in your code, and made a few small tweaks. The errors are - not eating the "whitespace" before the character input, using `fgets()` instead of `fgetc()`, using escape characters before the `'` symbols in the output text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)                                  // added arg for compilability
{
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[20];
    char character;
    int compare;                                // correct type for fgetc and toupper
    int to_upper1;
    int to_upper2;
    int count=0;
    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    scanf("%19s", filename);                    // restrict length
    fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Cannot open file '%s'\n", filename);
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("\nEnter the character to be counted: ");
    scanf(" %c", &character);                   // filter out whitespace
    to_upper1 = toupper((int)character);
    while((compare = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)         // changed from fgets()
    {
        to_upper2 = toupper(compare);
        if(to_upper1 == to_upper2)
          count++;
    }
    fclose(fp);                                 // remember to close file!
    printf("File '%s' has %d instances of letter '%c'", filename, count, character);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for your suggestions and pin pointing the errors in the code. it was of great help. when i compiled this code i got the expected output but when i submited it the compiler checks for other test cases and doesn't accept this code as valid :-( could you please let me figure out the problem.

Comment: Does the problem statement specify a format for the result output? For example, does it just want the character count. Another problem could be that it tried the program with a longer file name. Note the `filename[20]` and the `scanf("%19s", filename);`

Comment: @WeatherVane  This was the specification.                                                                   Sample Input and Output:
Enter the file name
test.txt
Enter the character to be counted
r
File 'test.txt' has 99 instances of letter 'r'.                                                     I just noticed i had missed out the full stop in the reult statement.

Comment: I put in colons `:` in the two prompts.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *fptr;
 int d=0;
  char c;
  char ch,ck;
  char b[100];
  printf("Enter the file name\n");
  scanf("%19s",b);
  fptr=fopen(b,"r");
  printf("Enter the character to be counted\n");
  scanf(" %c",&c);
  c=toupper(c);
  if(fptr==NULL)
  {
   exit(-1);
  }
while((ck=fgetc(fptr))!=EOF)
{
    ch=toupper(ck);
    if(c==ch||c==ck)
 ++d;
    }
  fclose(fptr);
 printf("File '%s' has %d instances of letter '%c'.",b,d,c);
        return(0);
        }
```